# Does Kubernetes (local Docker method) really work?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

As per the official documentation [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/) on running Kubernetes locally within a Container -- I have followed all the steps carefully, and I am still getting the message `connection refused` when I type `kubectl get nodes`.

`docker ps` shows that *api-server* is not running, and `docker logs kubelet` does indeed varify so:

```
[kubelet.go:1137] Unable to register 127.0.0.1 with the apiserver: Post http://localhost:8080/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused.
```

After a little while, `docker logs kubelet`

```
E0711 16:07:06.814735   33792 event.go:202] Unable to write event: 'Post http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/events: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused' (may retry after sleeping)
```

Apparently, I am not alone in experiencing this problem.

---

UPDATE:
After several hours, `docker logs kubelet`

```
E0712 08:28:03.528010   33792 pod_workers.go:138] Error syncing pod 4c6ab43ac4ee970e1f563d76ab3d3ec9, skipping: [failed to "StartContainer" for "controller-manager" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=controller-manager pod=k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default(4c6ab43ac4ee970e1f563d76ab3d3ec9)"
, failed to "StartContainer" for "apiserver" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=apiserver pod=k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default(4c6ab43ac4ee970e1f563d76ab3d3ec9)"
, failed to "StartContainer" for "setup" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=setup pod=k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default(4c6ab43ac4ee970e1f563d76ab3d3ec9)"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to run Kubernetes locally now is [Minikube](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/), though I'd expect the local docker method to still be functional.

Does `docker ps -a` show any crashed kube-apiserver containers that might have any clues in their logs?

Comment: I have tried Minikube and still get the same issues. I have updated the log (above) for the attempted start of api-server container. It does show that the container crashes.

Comment: :( that's frustrating. `docker logs kubelet` will tell you what kubelet is trying to do when it is starting the kubernetes containers. I'm wondering if there are any leftover logs from why those containers crashed (like a `docker logs apiserver` or something).

Comment: Nope. `docker logs apiserver` 
`Error: No such container: apiserver
`